# access a sharepoint file programmatically with Azure AD Application

Tags: .net, sharepoint, oauth, onedrive

I have an Azure AD Application and I have created an application.

[image]

I retrieve a user token but whenever I try to access a file in any sharepoint site, I'm getting an unauthorized.

What Am I missing? ( It looks like the delegated user token  is not allowed to access the file).
But if I paste the url in a browser, I have access to the file.

Here is the download code:

```
        using var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", userToken);
        var respons = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (respons.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var downloadStream = await respons.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        }
        else
        {

        }
```

I also tried with same unauthorized.

```
    string webUrl = "xxx";
    string fileUrl = "yyy";
    var requestUrl = String.Format("{0}/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/$value", webUrl, fileUrl);
```

Consent URL :
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantName/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=theclientID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_mode=query&scope=Files.ReadWrite.All&prompt=consent

or ( I tried to access files in shared onedrives or sharepoint sites).

https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantName/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=theclientID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_mode=query&scope=Sites.ReadWrite.All&prompt=consent

[image]

And the code for GetToken().

```
 private async Task<string> GetTokenForUserAsync()
    {
        _clientId ="xxx";
        _clientSecret ="yyy";
        _domainName ="zzz";
        string graphUrl = global::Utils.Tools.AzureURL.GetGraphUrl(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic);
        string loginUrl = global::Utils.Tools.AzureURL.GetLoginUrl(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic);
        loginUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", loginUrl, _domainName);
        string redirectUri = "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net";
        IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(_clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(loginUrl)
            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .Build();

        string[] scopes = new string[] { graphUrl + "/.default" };
        //string[] scopes = new string[] { graphUrl + "/Files.Read.All" };
        Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult result = null;
        result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        return result.AccessToken;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Token with clientId AND ClientSecret did not work.
I had to use clientId AND certicate.

It was not clearly mentioned anywhere.